Instrumental variable with measurement error
I have a question related to measurement error bias and the use of instrumental variables. Assume I have a continuous outcome variable $Y$ which is observed with no error and an endogenous (continuous) variable $X$ with measurement error. Let $Z$ be a (continuous) instrument of $X$ which satisfies the relevance and exogeneity conditions but $Z$ is also observed with measurement error. My data is panel and I use fixed effects.
Can I use $Z$ as an instrument on a two-stage least squares (2SLS) IV model and under what conditions?

Is the measurement error of $X$ related to its endogeneity? Is the cause for the measurement error in $Z$ the same as in $X$?

X is endogenous not only because of its measurement error but also because of omitted variable. The measurement error in Z is different from that of X.

With classical (i.e., independent and additive) measurement error, the attenuation bias in the first stage and reduced form will cancel each other out.
\begin{align*}
Y &= \beta X + u &\quad &(\text{Structural equation}) \\
X &= \theta Z + v &\quad &(\text{First stage})\\
Y &= \phi Z + \varepsilon &\quad &(\text{Reduced form})
\end{align*}
where $\varepsilon = \beta v + u $ and $\phi = \beta\theta$.
\begin{align*}
\theta &\neq 0 &\quad &(\text{Relevance}) \\
Cov(Z, u) &= 0 &\quad &(\text{Validity})
\end{align*}
Denote observed $X$ by $\tilde{X}$ and observed $Z$ by $\tilde{Z}$
$$ \tilde{X} = X + m_x $$
$$ \tilde{Z} = Z + m_z $$
where $m_x$ and $m_z$ are measurement errors that are assumed to be independent of each other, $Z$, $u$, and $v$. Regressing $Y$ and $\tilde{X}$ on $\tilde{Z}$ by OLS
$$ \hat{\phi}_{OLS} \overset{p}{\to} \frac{Cov(\tilde{Z},Y)}{Var(\tilde{Z})} = \frac{Cov(Z + m_z, \beta\theta Z + \beta v + u)}{Var(Z + m_z)} = \frac{\beta\theta Var(Z) + \beta Cov(Z,v)}{Var(Z) + Var(m_z)} $$
$$ \hat{\theta}_{OLS} \overset{p}{\to} \frac{Cov(\tilde{Z},\tilde{X})}{Var(\tilde{Z})} = \frac{Cov(Z + m_z, \theta Z + v + m_x)}{Var(Z + m_z)} = \frac{\theta Var(Z) + Cov(Z,v)}{Var(Z) + Var(m_z)} $$
Even though neither the first stage nor the reduced form are estimated consistently, the IV estimator for $\beta$ is still consistent becasue both the first stage and reduced form are biased in the same way
$$\hat{\beta}_{IV} = \frac{\hat{\phi}_{OLS}}{\hat{\theta}_{OLS}} \overset{p}{\to} \frac{\beta\left(\theta Var(Z) + Cov(Z,v)\right)/\left(Var(Z) + Var(m_z)\right)}{\left(\theta Var(Z) + Cov(Z,v)\right)/\left(Var(Z) + Var(m_z)\right)} = \beta  $$
Assuming $Cov(Z, v) = 0$ to focus only on the role of the measurement error, we have
$$ \hat{\phi}_{OLS} \overset{p}{\to} \beta\theta\lambda$$
$$ \hat{\theta}_{OLS} \overset{p}{\to} \theta\lambda$$
$$ \lambda = \frac{Var(Z)}{Var(Z) + Var(m_z)}$$
The first stage and reduced form will be biased towards zero by the same degree, becasue $0 \leq \lambda \leq 1$.
To investigate how the panel-dimension of your data and your use of fixed effects will influence this result, you'll have to add subscripts (unit $i$, period $t$; $N$ units, $T$ periods) and within transform the variables. For example, within-transformed $Y_{it}$ (with unit fixed effects) is $Y_{it} - \bar{Y}_i$, where $\bar{Y}_i = \frac{1}{T} \sum_1^T Y_{it}$. Then write the probability limit of the reduced form fixed-effects estimator as
$$ \hat{\phi}_{FE} \overset{p}{\to} \frac{Cov(\tilde{Z}_{it} -\bar{\tilde{Z}}_{i},Y_{it} - \bar{Y}_{i})}{Var(\tilde{Z}_{it} -\bar{\tilde{Z}}_{i})} = \frac{Cov(Z_{it} + m_{z,it} -\bar{Z}_{i} - \bar{m}_{z,i},\beta\theta Z_{it} + \beta v_{it} + u_{it} - \beta\theta \bar{Z}_{i} - \beta\bar{v}_i - \bar{u}_i)}{Var(Z_{it} + m_{z,it} -\bar{Z}_{i} - \bar{m}_{z,i})} $$
If you exapand, the numerator will turn into a straigtforward but very long sum of covariances. Some of these might be cancelled by corresponding terms in the first-stage estimator, but others will have to be zero by assumption. Compared to the cross-section case, it will be necessary to assume that $Z_{it}$ is uncorrelated with $u_{is}$ for all $s = 1, ..., T$ (strict exogeneity).
If you're not assuming classical measurement errors, you'll have to determine what kind of dependence is alright and what is not. If I'm not mistaken, autocorrelation in $m_{z,it}$ should not matter, becasue $m_{z,it}$ only shows up to the left in the covariance expression. My intuition is that both $Z_{it}$ and $m_{z,it}$ have to be strictly exogenous with respect to $u_{it}$ and $m_{x,it}$.
REFERENCES

Ashenfelter, O., & Krueger, A. (1994). Estimates of the economic return to schooling from a new sample of twins. The American Economic Review, 1157-1173. https://www.jstor.org/stable/2117766
Angrist, J. D., & Pischke, J. S. (2014). Mastering 'Metrics: The path from cause to effect. Princeton university press. Appendix, Chapter 6.


Thanks so much for the analytic answer. This is really helpful

May I ask a follow up question? What would it mean if measurement errors m_z were autocorrelated (recall my data is panel)?

No problem. I've tried to address the panel dimension now.
